# Select Top 5 or Limit to 5 entries on Get-WmiObject Powershell query

Tags: c#, sql, wmi-query

I'm perfoming queries on the event viewer `(Win32_NTLogEvent)` 
Is there anyway to just select the top 10 or max 5 return events

I had already try with `TOP`, `LIMIT` or `ROWCOUNT` but nothing works

```
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE (SourceName = "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" and EventCode = "41")'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) doesn't support the `TOP`, `LIMIT` or `ROWCOUNT` keywords; instead, you'll need to pipe the results to the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet and select the `-First 10` rows, e.g.:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE (SourceName = "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" and EventCode = "41")' | select -First 10
```

You may also need to pipe the results through the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet first, so that the results are sorted by a given property prior to selection.